# How to redirect https traffic through ssh tunnel?

Tags: ssh

I have host.local at my intranet with a dynamic IP. I have another server host.com at internet with a fixed static IP. What I want is to redirect all the https traffic from host.com:443 to my host.local:443.

I have been using VPN solution however decide to switch to ssh tunnel. I wonder what's the command line that I should issue from host.local to setup a ssh tunnel to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

1:Open PuTTY.EXE, configure your host name, and select SSH for port like you do in order to connect.

2: we have to configure the ports for tunneling, so for that go to Click on SSH->Tunnels

3: In the Port forwarding section, the Source Port is the source TCP/IP address you want assigned to your local host connection. In the Port forwarding section, the Source Port is the source TCP/IP address you want assigned to your local host connection.

[image]

4:Click the Add button to place your tunnel configuration in the Forwarded ports window

5:Now In the left panel, click on Session to bring up the following window. Click on the Save button:

[image]

6:Now you can launch your session and sign in to the secure shell. After you are signed in, you must leave this window open to keep your tunnel active.

You can tunnel multiple ports if you like; however, all require that the PuTTY secure shell connection stays active for data to pass over the tunnel to the remote server.

The steps above are represented as the following command on a UNIX system:

```
ssh -L50000:localhost:23 my.test.server.com
```

The steps above are represented as the following command on the command line:

```
ssh -T -L50000:localhost:23 my.test.server.com
```

Also as long as the session is active you can use those ports in the web browser to surf with putty , for example in firefox..:

```
TOOLS->OPTIONS->NETWORK TAB->SETTINGS->MANUAL PROXY CONFIGURATION
```

now you can add this in HTTP PROXY :

```
localhost or 127.0.0.1
```

And in the Ports

```
Add the port you forwarded , in our case it was 50000
```